# Loop and graph with the results of simulation are not working

Tags: loops, macros, simulation

`proc` import `datafile`= '/home/u62192016/FINA 6271- `MSF` 2022/Assets.`xlsx`'
`dbms`=`xlsx` out=original_data replace;
run;

data pd_table;
length `RatingNum` $3. PD1-PD5 8.;
input `RatingNum` $ PD1-PD5;
`datalines`;
1 0.0000 0.0300 0.1300 0.2400 0.3400
2 0.0200 0.0600 0.1400 0.2500 0.3500
3 0.0500 0.1300 0.2200 0.3300 0.4600
4 0.1600 0.4300 0.7500 1.1400 1.5400
5 0.6300 1.9300 3.4600 4.9900 6.4300
6 3.3400 7.8000 11.7500 14.8900 17.3500
;
run;

data assets_pd_horizon;
set assets_pd_rating;
if `RatingNum`=1 then PD_horizon= (0.148+6)/100;
else if `RatingNum`=2 then PD_horizon= (0.164+6)/100;
else if `RatingNum`=3 then PD_horizon= (0.238+6)/100;
else if `RatingNum`=4 then PD_horizon= (0.804+6)/100;
else if `RatingNum`=5 then PD_horizon= (3.488+6)/100;
else if `RatingNum`=6 then PD_horizon= (11.026+6)/100;
output;
run;

`proc` print data=assets_pd_horizon;
run;

%macro simulate(n=1);
data `SimulationLoop`;
length Simulation $100 `DefaultNum` 8;
run;
%do `sin_num`= 1 %to &n;
%let factor_loading=5;
data assignment;
set original_data;
Horizon=5;
Factor_loading= &factor_loading;
`proc` print data=assignment;
run;
data Assets;
do Asset= 1 to 200;
if Asset=1 then do;
S1 = `probit`(RAND("uniform"));
S2 = `probit`(RAND("uniform"));
S3 = `probit`(RAND("uniform"));
S4 = `probit`(RAND("uniform"));
S5 = `probit`(RAND("uniform"));
`Zi` = `probit`(RAND("uniform"));
end;
output;
if Asset>1 then do;
S1=S1;
S2=S2;
S3=S3;
S4=S4;
`Zi=probit`(RAND("uniform"));
end;
output;
end;
run;

```
            `proc` print data=Assets;
            run;
        
            data combined_data;
             merge Assets assignment; 
            run;
        
            `proc` print data=combined_data;
            run;
        
            data assets_xi; set combined_data;
                Xi = (F1*S1 + F2*S2 + F3*S3 + F4*S4 + F5*S5) + 
                (`Zi` * `SQRT`  (1 - F1**2+ F2**2 + F3**2 + F4**2 +F5**2));
            run;
        
            `proc` print data=assets_xi;
            run;
        
            data `assets_ui`;set assets_xi;
                do `Ui` = `cdf`("Normal", Xi);
                    output;
                end;
            run;
        
            `proc` print data=`assets_ui`;
            run;
        
            data assets_pd; set `assets_ui`; 
                `proc` format;
                    value $`rating_to_num`
                    'AAA'=1
                    'AA'=2
                    'A'=3
                    'BBB'=4
                    'BB'=5
                    'B'=6;
                run;
        
                data assets_pd_rating;
                    set assets_pd;
                    `RatingNum` = input(put(Rating, $`rating_to_num`.), 8.);
                    drop Rating;
                run;
        
                `proc` print data=assets_pd_rating;
                run;
        
                data rating_pd; set pd_table;
                    `Average_PDs`= (sum(PD1+PD2+PD3+PD4+PD5)/5);
                run;
        
        
                data assets_pd_rating_default;
                    length default $3;
                    set assets_pd_horizon;
                    retain Default;
                    if `Ui` > PD_horizon then Default='No';
                    else Default= 'Yes';
                    output;
                run;
        
                `proc` print data=assets_pd_rating_default;
                run;
        
                `proc` freq data=assets_pd_rating_default;
                    tables Default / `nocum nocol norow`;
                run;
                
                data assets_default;
                    set assets_pd_rating_default;
                    if _N_ < 201 or _N_ > 2010 then output;
                run;
        
                data `assets_defaultNum`; set assets_default;
                    if Default='Yes' then `DefaultNum` = 1;
                    else `DefaultNum` = 0;
                run;
                
                `proc` print data=`assets_defaultNum`;
                run;
                
                `proc` freq data=`assets_DefaultNum`;
                    tables `DefaultNum` / `nocum nocol norow`;
                run;
        
                `proc sql noprint`;
                    select count(*) as `DefaultNum`
                    from simulation
                    where `DefaultNum`= 1;
                quit;
                `proc` append base=simulation data=`DefaultNum` force; run;
            %end;
%mend simulate;
```

%simulate (n=100);

`proc` freq data=simulation `noprint`;
tables `DefaultNum` / out=`freqout`;
run;

`proc sgplot data=Freqout`;
`vbar` `DefaultNum` / response=Percent `datalabel`;
`yaxis` label="Probability";
`xaxis` label="Number of defaults";
run;
i am supposed to get a `proc` freq data table at the end with all the defaults simulations, counting yes default (or 1 since i identify Yes=1) and the `sglot` graph of those simulations.